# How to further improve English listening?

Tags: discussion

I can easily understand the conversation from Twitch or Live Youtuber shows. However, when I watch shows on Netflix or Amazon Prime videos, I cannot understand their talks...  It looks like I listen to other unfamiliar languages...

It is very frustrating to me. Could you please give me any suggestions for me to improve my listening? I don't know what is the problem with my ears... I was thinking about probably the shows from Netflix or Amazon is more difficult than the ones from Twitch or Youtuber. Thanks.

Comment: Are you watching action or Super heroes movies on Netflix? Don't. The dialogue tends to be of low quality and often consists of shouting or mumbles. For now, stick to documentaries, drama, and... interviews by late night hosts. I love Graham Norton (UK), he's witty and the guests stay longer than 6 minutes as is often the case with American Talk shows.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for your great sharing. I recently watch the show called NCIS on Netflix. Unfortunately, my listening doesn't work for the show. I will try the show you mention. Thanks again.

Comment: Today's programs seem to be full of actors that mumble and slur their words.  Try watching old programs (e.g. before 1970) and you'll be amazed at how much better your hearing becomes. (I often have to have subtitles on in order to understand what people are saying in my native English language. But old shows are no problem.)